# Total pages number appears as question mark

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

In my document, I use this script:

```
%the template
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%for foot page numdering
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\number\value{page} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}{}             
%end page numbering

\begin{document}

%\includepdf[pages={17-23}]{master_paper.pdf}
\title{Document Title}
\author{Name Here}
%\\Supervised by: Prof. Cas Cremers
\institute{Institution)\\
\email{zz@yy.com}}

\maketitle 

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here..
\end{abstract}


\section Section Here

\end{document}
```

The problem is that, when I view the document in PDF format, at the buttom of the page, the page numdering does not appear properly. It appears as: `1 of ??` i.e. it does not show the total number of pages as supposed.

Comment: try add `\usepackage{lastpage}` into your preamble ...

Comment: Did you compile the document twice? The first run saves the number of pages while the second ``replaces'' the ?? by the proper number. I don't have that document class so can't test myself.

Answer (score 3):

The `\usepackage{lastpage}` was missing, so `\pageref{LastPage}` provides nothing than `??`

Alternatively, I have shown the way with `xassoccnt` and its `TotalDocumentCounter` feature, associated to the page counter. This has the advantage that even after an eventual `\pagenumbering{...}` command the total page numbers is not affected, but `LastPage` would show a different value.

In both cases, compiling twice is necessary!

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}

%for foot page numdering
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\number\value{page} of \TotalValue{totalpages} or with LastPage reference: \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}{}             
%end page numbering

\begin{document}

%\includepdf[pages={17-23}]{master_paper.pdf}
\title{Document Title}
\author{Name Here}
%\\Supervised by: Prof. Cas Cremers
\institute{Institution)\\
\email{zz@yy.com}}

\maketitle 

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here..
\end{abstract}


\section Section Here


\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]